# See Stack Overflow statistics

Tags: support, statistics

I have been looking at the Redmonk programming language rankings at the [Redmonk website](https://redmonk.com/sogrady/2018/08/10/language-rankings-6-18/). Redmonk says they use the number of questions asked on each programming language on Stack Overflow. Is there a way to view these statistics?

Comment: Related: [Using Stack Overflow to track language popularity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37689/194720), the [results of the last developer survey (2018)](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/), [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), etc.

Comment: Maybe they use StackOverflow trends: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends

Comment: Did you even read the link you gave? It literally says *For Stack Overflow, we simply collect the required metrics using their useful [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) tool.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that they use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), when you can run SQL queries against a copy of StackOverflow database (or any of the sites of the Stack Exchange network). Yes, they provide full access to the data (excluding personal user information) and also offer a web interface to run queries without having to download all that GB (although you can download it if you want). Very cool in my opinion.

Searching for 'language' I found this query:

[Language trends (# of Question Views per Month)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/909662/language-trends-of-question-views-per-month#graph)

Since that query doesn't include every language tag use the `fork query` link to create a new query based on it and edit this part of the SQL code to include/exclude the language tags:

```
Tags.TagName IN (
    'php', 'python', 'c#', 'c++', 'ruby', 'c', 'objective-c', 'go', 'swift', 'r', 'rust', 'clojure', 'scheme'
  )
```

Also you can use this query to get the full tag list:

[Get all tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/172362/get-all-tags)

Comment: From the article linked by OP: "For Stack Overflow, we simply collect the required metrics using their useful data explorer tool."